# Fundo preto na aplicação cordova

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, xcode

Estou tendo um problema, uma das páginas da minha aplicação (para o iPhone 4s esse problema está em todas as páginas), tem um fundo preto atrás de todo o conteúdo, quando eu faço o bounce do iPhone (touch arrastando pra baixo depois para cima, além do limite da tela) no iPhone 4s esse problema também aparece entre as divs e pelo GapDebug eu não consigo ver onde ela é definida.

Estou usando o Cordova 6.3.1.

Já tentei o seguinte:

A opção Status Bar Style Light no XCode,

```
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />

<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />

<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#c0c0c0" />
```

mas nada altera isso, segue as capturas de tela:

[Esta é a tela padrão e correta no iPhone 5+, o overscroll está com a cor correta que é definida pelo css do body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGTkK.png)

[Em outra página, rodando também no iPhone 5+ quando eu dou o Bouce(overscroll)  aparece o fundo preto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmmwD.png)

[No iPhone 4S aparece o fundo preto entre as divs até mesmo na tela inicial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFDLE.png)

[E no Bounce (overscroll) também](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqTHi.png)

O problema é que no iPhone 5+ o fundo preto no overscroll somente acontece em uma página da aplicação, nas outras está padrão cinza (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwC6R.png)

PS: Não consigo colocar mais que 2 links no meu post porque a minha reputação é menor que 10.

Comment: nunca tive esse tipo de problema, mas nao consigo imaginar outra coisa alem de css, ate por que a cor default do body do navegador é branco, pelo menos a maioria é branco. Se puder posta o css tambem

Comment: Já testei, se eu inspeciono pelo GapDebug, em nenhum lugar diz que o background tá definido pra preto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolução:

Eu estava procurando por alguma classe que definisse o preto que aparecia, black ou #000000, mas na verdade o que estava definindo de algum jeito era uma classe CSS que estava sendo inserida por outra biblioteca JavaScript que eu utilizava.

```
.app-content {
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```